# Access object from another button click event

Tags: c#, class, object, button

I'm fairly new to C# so this might be pretty simple actually though I have spent a couple hours searching without a solution.

I'm working with windows form and I am trying to access an object from another button-click event. The error I'm getting is "The name 'object' does not exist in the current context" when trying to access object in Button2_Click.

```
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Prefilled with a persons info
        MyClass object = new MyClass();
    }

    public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Access object
        string name = object.Name;
    }
```

So my question is how do I access an object created in another "Button_Click"?

Comment: You've defined object in a function scope so it's got garbage collected after the function code is executed. You might want to define it in class scope instead. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the `object` should be class level in order to be used by other methods in the same class:

```
private MyClass _myClassObject; // class level object. Remember "object" is reserved keyword that is why renamed it to "_myClassObject"
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Prefilled with a persons info
        _myClassObject = new MyClass();
}

public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Access object
    string name = _myClassObject.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues exists.

1. You can't use `object` as variable name. (`object` is a reserved keyword)
2. You can't access a internal variable, within another event.

To solve your issue, you would scope the variable when your initial object is created.

```
public class Example
{
     // Variable declared as a class global.
     private readonly Sample sample; 

     // Constructor to build our sample.
     public Example() => sample = new Sample(); 

     // Button writing a property from sample.
     protected void btnSend(object sender, EventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine(sample.SomeProperty); 
}
```

So the object is in the upper portion of your class, when you build Example, a sample is always created.  So as you utilize `Sample` within your `Example` class, it will be correctly scoped.

I also don't understand why you have to click one button, to populate this object, so I altered to have the object built once `Example` is created.

Comment: c# 6 syntax might be confusing for someone who is just getting started with c#

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Fair enough, I use the shorthand quite a bit.  Second nature to me at this point.